# Navigation links wont work with z-index

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstraps as css in my code. I need to put an image over the nav bar...but if I try z-index my links wont work,tried z-index as 0 for navbar,the navbar overlaps the image,tried as -1 works fine but disables the links

Following is my Code:

```
<div class="container " style="width:30%;float:left;">

<img class="brand" src="img.png" style="z-index:2;" />
 </div>
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top " style="z-index:-1;" >
<div class="container"style="width:50%;">
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

    <li class="active"><a href=href="#">One</a></li>    
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Four</a></li>    
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why not just use a css `background-image`? What is the purpose of the image on top of the nav bar?

Comment: What do you mean *"links wont work"* ? Links are not clickable..? If you place an element on top of the links then how do you expect to click them..? Please elaborate what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

Update your HTML as mentioned below :

```
<div class="container " style="width:30%;float:left;z-index:0;">

<img class="brand" src="http://images.tentebranda.org/wp-content/uploads/photo-background-images_8713_1.jpg"  />
 </div>
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top " style="z-index:1;" >
<div class="container"style="width:50%;">
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href=href="#">One</a></li>    
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Four</a></li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it sends the image behind the navbar

Comment: no i just need it to be overlapped with height and width specified,it is actually working on js-fiddle but its not working on codeigniter.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Evs59/1/